# Request Response Headers different to Web browsers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am working on a Bot to purchase me an item as it's hard to get. I have got to the payment stage and need to make one more post. It requires a link returned by a header in a post before this one.

The response header in chrome has a Location value but on requests it's not giving me that.

Requests Return Headers:
`{'Allow': 'HEAD, GET', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Server': '', 'Expires': 'Sat, 26 Feb 2022 04:27:52 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Sat, 26 Feb 2022 04:27:52 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': 'AKA_A2=A; expires=Sat, 26-Feb-2022 05:27:52 GMT; path=/; domain=payments.woolworths.com.au; secure; HttpOnly', 'Server-Timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=MISS, edge; dur=8, origin; dur=12', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains'`

Chrome Returned Headers:

```
content-length: 0
date: Sat, 26 Feb 2022 05:10:16 GMT
expires: Sat, 26 Feb 2022 05:10:16 GMT
location: https://www.bigw.com.au/checkout/webpay/success?dts_reference=00000000000
pragma: no-cache
server
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
server-timing: edge; dur=108
server-timing: origin; dur=298
set-cookie: AKA_A2=A; expires=Sat, 26-Feb-2022 06:10:16 GMT; path=/; domain=payments.woolworths.com.au; secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
```

My headers are:

```
'authority': 'iframe.payments.woolworths.com.au',
'method': 'POST',
'path': '/WOWPaymentService/webservice/continueSecureData',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'content-length': '147',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'dnt': '1',
'origin': 'https://iframe.payments.woolworths.com.au',
'referer': 'https://iframe.payments.woolworths.com.au/WOWPaymentService/webservice/continueSecureData',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'iframe',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'
```

Data:

```
"card_number": "4007000000027",
"exp_month": "03",
"exp_year": "2024",
"cv2_number": "456",
"HPS_SessionID": f"{str(paymentid)}",
"issue_number": "" ,
"action": "confirm",
```

If you need any extra information let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the actual code of your request? What headers are you sending?

Comment: @NickBailey sorry I forgot to add that, take a look now!